# Copy autofiltered range, vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have written the code that does the following:

1. applies autofilter to specific `sheet` in the selected `workbook`
2. copies data from `autofiltered range` except the header to another `workbook`

Here is the code:

```
 m = 2 
 For i = 1 To work_book.Worksheets.Count 
With work_book.Sheets(i) 
    If (.UsedRange.Rows.Count > 1) Then 
         'apply filters
        .UsedRange.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=array_of_account_numbers, Operator:=xlFilterValues 
        .UsedRange.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=array_of_debit_or_credits, Operator:=xlFilterValues 
         'select only visible cells after autofilter is applied
        On Error Goto a 
        m = destination_workbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1 
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & m) 
 a: 
    End If 
   End With
```

However, macro persistently copies some garbage. It means that it copies from each `sheet` first three `rows` in addition to `autofiltered range`.

How can I solve this issue? I will appreciate for your help and your answers.

EDIT

Here is the example of the data in worksheet

[image: example of data]

Filter is applied to Criteria1 (<> 60, <>50) and to Criteria2 (<>1470, <>1450)

Answer (score 1):

`.UsedRange` will grab all the data on your source sheet, not just data below the auto-filtered results.

The `Offset` that you use in your `Intersect...Copy` statement should be the number of rows above your auto-filtered results that you want to ignore, instead of the value 1.

If you know how many header rows you have:

```
numHeaderRows = 5
For i = 1 To work_book.Worksheets.Count 
  With work_book.Sheets(i) 
    If (.UsedRange.Rows.Count > 1) Then 
         'apply auto-filters starting at the row directly above the start of the data.
        .UsedRange.Offset(numHeaderRows-1).AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=array_of_account_numbers, Operator:=xlFilterValues 
        .UsedRange.Offset(numHeaderRows-1).AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=array_of_debit_or_credits, Operator:=xlFilterValues 
         'select only visible cells after autofilter is applied
        On Error Goto a 
        m = destination_workbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1 
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(numHeaderRows)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy destination_workbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & m) 
  a: 
    End If 
  End With
Next
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. About `Offset`, I need to remove header from selected range, that's why I used value 1. What do you suggest instead of `.UsedRange` ?

Comment: You can still use `UsedRange`, just increase your Offset value enough so that the rows above the auto-filtered data are not included.

Comment: That's kinda a problem because I don't how many rows above the selected range =)

Comment: @fsua, Yes, I see now. You are filtering the entire worksheet contents, including the several (unspecified) rows of header data.  You will either need to know how many rows of header data you have, or if your data is always in a particular style or format, you can write code to try to detect the first row of good data, so you know where the data starts.

Comment: Suppose, I know how many rows there in my data header (say 5), then can you suggest what code should I write?

Comment: @fsua, I edited the code in my answer to account for knowing how many header rows exist in the worksheet.